# Having three measures field under three different categories (total 6 columns). I need to colour code all six columns with six different thresholds

Tags: colors, tableau-api, desktop

Please see the attached excel and that shows how my output should be ... given all the thresholds and more information on it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akcsA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbPYE.png)

The above attached image is how my output should look like

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image, it looks like the three different measures (Sales, Quantity, Profit) and three different categories (Furniture, Office Supplies, Technology).

You can set individual thresholds for each by creating parameters.

In Tableau, in the data column, right click and select Create > Parameters...

From there, you can create calculated fields to evaluate if the data values are greater than the thresholds.